# Testing Django view: how can we know if catched exception was actually raised?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, exception

I want to test if exceptions in my views are raised when expected. The "issue" I am facing with is that I am using `try` and `except` statements in my view, so I actually **catch** those exceptions (in order to do some stuff when they are raised).

My question is the following: **how can I test if one expected `exception` was raised, if it was catched in my `except` statement?**

For instance:

**myviews.py**

```
class SomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = models.MyModel
    template_name = "my_template.html"
    form_class = forms.MyForm       
    def form_valid(self, form):

        try:
             # normal stuff here
             return super(SomeView, self).form_valid(form)

        except Exception1 as e:
             # some other stuff here
             print("Exception1 occured: ", e)
             messages.error(self.request, "Message1")
             return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

        except Exception2 as e:
             # some other stuff here
             print("Exception2 occured: ", e)
             messages.error(self.request, "Message2")
             return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

        except Exception as e:
             # some other stuff here
             print("Something unexpected occured! ", e)
             messages.error(self.request, "Message_unexpected")
             return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

**mytests.py**

```
def test_SomeView(self):

    # test: everything must works just fine
    form_data = some_valid_data
    response = self.client.post("some_url", form_data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    # test: Exception1 should be raised in SomeView
    form_data = some_NOT_valid_data # on purpose
    response = self.client.post(reverse("some_url"), form_data)
    for message in list(response.context['messages']): print(message) 
    # UPDATE1 - no message is print, 
    # even if they are displayed as expected on my real web page 
    # when doing willingly bad stuff
```

Many thanks for your help!

---

### UPDATE1

Originally, I wanted to do this:

```
form_data = some_NOT_valid_data
self.assertRaises(
        Exception1,
        lambda: self.client.post("some_url"), form_data)
    )
```

but then I changed my mind regarding jonrsharpe comment (*testing behaviour more than implementation*). So I tried to get generated error messages when `Exceptions` were caught so I would be able to check if they were what I expected. But I can't get any `context message` apparently, even if they are displayed as expected in my template! And yet `context`is not empty.

---

### UPDATE2 - Answer to my own question

I finally found how to manage that. I tried for instance to add `follow=True` (as in `response = self.client.post("some_url", form_data, follow=True)` but this was incorrect because it was not a redirection but same view was rendered once again with a different context. So, what I did is the following:

For each `except` statement in my view:

```
except Exception1 as e:
    # some other stuff here
    print("Exception1 occured: ", e)
    messages.error(self.request, "Message1")
    return self.render_to_response(context=self.get_context_data(form=form, messages=list(messages.get_messages(self.request))))
```

Also, in my view, I overrided my `get_context_data` method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if 'messages' in kwargs: context['messages'] = kwargs['messages']
    return context
```

Then, finally, in my test I was able to get excepted messages:

```
response = self.client.post("some_url", form_data)
self.assertTrue("part_of_message" in str(response.context.get('messages')[0]))
```

And it works!

Comment: You can't test that it was actually raised, **because it wasn't raised**. You caught it. That's what the code you've written is for. Don't test implementation, test *behaviour*; in this case, that the right thing is passed to `messages.error`.

Comment: Ok I get the idea! Sounds logical now to process that way (testing behaviour more than implementation). Sorry you have to tell me that, still learning the proper way to dot that kind of tests. I have updated my question and my code (see #UPDATE1 in 2 minutes), but I still can't extract any message from context in order to see if it was what I expected. But if I test it myself (by being a real user of my website), expected error message is displayed! So it has to be part of my context...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded (see my own **Update 2**), with the indication of @jonrsharpe. It was better to test behaviour than testing absolutely what I wanted at first (if an `exception` was raised, then catched). So I struggled with testing if error `messages` were correctly generated, and after correcting a few mistakes of my own I finally got something that worked! Or didn't work, but as expected: well you get the idea.